# redux-saga test while(true) - make saga.next().done true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

I am testing a polling saga.

```
export function* sagaWithPolling() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      // saga body
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(stopPolling());
      yield put(displayError(error));
    }
  }
}
```

TEST:

```
 describe('error flow', () => {
    const saga = sagaWithPolling();

    saga.next();

    test('stop polling', () => {
      const actual = saga.throw(TEST_ERROR).value;
      const expected = put(stopPolling());

      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

    test('should display error', () => {
      const actual = saga.next().value;
      const expected = put(displayError(TEST_ERROR));

      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });

    test('be done', () => {
      const actual = saga.next().done;
      const expected = true;

      expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
    });
  });
```

This test passes for normal sagas, but here for polling and the one with `while(true)` it fails in the last step because `saga.next().done` is false, as it continues polling. Any ideas how to point that it stopped polling?

Answer (score 0):

Since an infinite loop defined in the generator, `gen.next()` will let the generator infinite `yield` value in that infinite loop(`try` block). The value is always the `{value: 1, done: false}`. The generator will **NEVER** finish.

You should use [Generator.prototype.return()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) to return the given value and finishes the generator.

E.g.

`saga.ts`:

```
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects';

export function stopPolling() {
  return { type: 'STOP_POLLING' };
}
export function displayError(error) {
  return { type: 'DISPLAY_ERROR', payload: error };
}

export function* sagaWithPolling() {
  while (true) {
    try {
      // saga body
      yield 1;
    } catch (error) {
      yield put(stopPolling());
      yield put(displayError(error));
    }
  }
}
```

`saga.test.ts`:

```
import { put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { displayError, sagaWithPolling, stopPolling } from '.';

describe('error flow', () => {
  const saga = sagaWithPolling();
  const TEST_ERROR = new Error('network');

  saga.next();

  test('stop polling', () => {
    const actual = saga.throw(TEST_ERROR).value;
    const expected = put(stopPolling());
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });

  test('should display error', () => {
    const actual = saga.next().value;
    const expected = put(displayError(TEST_ERROR));
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });

  test('be done', () => {
    const actual = saga.return().done;
    const expected = true;
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/65237271/index.test.ts
  error flow
    ✓ stop polling (3 ms)
    ✓ should display error (1 ms)
    ✓ be done

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.067 s, estimated 3 s
```